Pie Chart labels overlapping and getting clipped in react chart js 2
In the following code, the pie chart's labels are overlapping and clipping at the top. How can I prevent this?
For the following code, the labels that are used not only overlap but clip as well. How can I fix this?
import {Pie} from 'react-chartjs-2';
function getRandomColor() {
    const digits = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    const opacity_digits = 'CDEF';
    let color = '#';
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      color += digits[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        color += opacity_digits[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
    }
    return color;
}

const backgroundColors = sortedKeys.map(() => getRandomColor());

const shiftLegendPlugin = {
    id: 'shiftLegend',
    beforeInit(chart) {
      const originalFit = chart.legend.fit;
      chart.legend.fit = function fit() {
        originalFit.bind(chart.legend)();
        this.left += 40;
      };
    }
  };

  Chart.register(shiftLegendPlugin);

const pieOptions = {
    layout: {
        padding: 20
    },
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    responsive: false,
    plugins: {
        legend: {
            display: true, 
            color: '#0000a0',
            text: "Sales per category",
            position: 'right', 
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: '#0000a0',
            labels: {
                color: '#000000', 
                font: {
                    family: 'Calibri',
                    size: 12
                }
            }
        },
        datalabels: {
            textAlign: 'center',
            font: {
                family: 'Calibri',
                color: '#000000',
                size: 14
            },
            formatter: (value, ctx) => {
                let sum = 0;
                let dataArr = ctx.chart.data.datasets[0].data;
                dataArr.map(data => {
                    sum += data;
                });
                let percentage = (value * 100 / sum).toFixed(2) + "%";
                let label = ctx.chart.data.labels[ctx.dataIndex];
                return label + ': ' + percentage;
            },
            anchor: 'end', 
            align: 'end', 
            offset: 10,
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: true,
            backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
            titleColor: '#000000',
            bodyColor: '#000000',
            titleFont: {
                family: 'Calibri',
                size: 14,
            },
            bodyFont: {
                family: 'Calibri',
                size: 12,
            },
            displayColors: true,
            mode: 'index',
            caretPadding: 10,
            caretSize: 5,
        },
        shiftLegendPlugin,
    
    }
}

const pieData = {
    labels: sortedKeys,
    datasets: [{
        data: sortedValues,
        backgroundColor: backgroundColors,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#fffffff',
        hoverOffset: 20
    }]
};


<div className="pie-chart">
    <Pie data = {pieData} options = {pieOptions} height={400} width={800} ></Pie>
</div>

Pie chart image
I tried changing css attributes like height and position of the canvas generated on rendering but doesn't work, the top stays clipped.
